# Spring как обратиться к внешнему ключу

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-jpa

Есть две таблицы/сущности.

```java
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "employee")
public class Employee {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer employeeId;
    private String name;
    private Integer salary;
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn
    private Position position;
```

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "position")
public class Position {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer positionId;
    
    private String role;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "position")
    private List<Employee> employeeList= new ArrayList<Employee>();
    
    public Position()
}
```

Таблицу `Employee` нужно заполнить при помощи JSON следующего вида:

```json
{
    "name": "zita",
    "salary": 123456,
    "position": {
        "positionId": 1
    }
}
```

А вторая таблица `position` уже заполнена.

При каждой попытке заполнить таблицу `Employee` возникает ошибка, что таблица заполнена без внешнего ключа.

Как можно достучаться до внешнего ключа?

Comment: Можно у `Employee` завести ещё одно поле `int positionId`. А у поля `position` в аннотации `@JoinColumn` указать `insertable = false` и `updatable = false`. Это чтобы Хибернейт не ругался, что два поля ссылаются на одну колонку в БД. И тогда по идее получится таким JSON-ом вставить работника с существующим отделом.

Comment: так создаем отдельное поле в Employee, а  мне надо чтобы заполнялся внешний ключ он по прежнему пуст , чтобы была связь между таблицами.

Comment: Если так сделать, то как раз-таки в БД внешний ключ и заполнится